# Action between certain time

Tags: python, datetime, time, action

What I want to achieve is running specified action when the time is between xx and yy.

(Using the 24 hour format)

Ex.

1. When hour and minute is *higher* than 23:30 and *lower* than 06:15 then **run specified action**.
2. When hour and minute is *higher* than 06:15 and *lower* than 09:00 then **run specified action**.
3. When hour and minute is *higher* than 09:00 and *lower* than 23:30 then **run specified action**.

**When have I tried:**

```
self.data = 0
localtime = time.strftime("%H%M", time.localtime())
localtime = int(localtime)
if localtime >= 2330 and localtime < 615 and self.data != 1:
     [..] //running certain action
     self.data = 1
elif localtime >= 615 and localtime < 900 and self.data != 2:
     [..] //running certain action
     self.data = 2
elif localtime >= 900 and localtime < 2330 and self.data != 3:
     [..] //running certain action
     self.data = 3
```

As you can see, the only problem with my code is that `localtime` can not be *higher* than 2330 and *lower* than 615 at once, and so on. The only **other** idea I got is to create an array with all 24 hours listed and specify a certain action that way... but is there maybe other way to achieve what I want?

Comment: seems to me like you would want to be using `or` for the first condition, not `and`

Comment: Small syntax comment: You can use `if x < N < y` like `if 615 <= localtime <= 900` instead of using `and`.

Comment: @Julius Yes, seems easy and funny now... I dont know why didnt I think of that... Thanks!

Comment: @Sberry Thank you , seems useful even though `and` was the problem here I will use that way in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be use `or` instead of `and`?

```
if (localtime >= 2330 or localtime < 615) and self.data != 1:
```

or

```
if localtime >= 615 and localtime < 900:
     if self.data != 2
         [..] //running certain action
         self.data = 2
elif localtime >= 900 and localtime < 2330:
     if self.data != 3
         [..] //running certain action
         self.data = 3
else:
     if self.data != 1
         [..] //running certain action
         self.data = 1
```